# Leopard Gecko Tail drop 1+ years ago not grown back

Tags: health, leopard-geckos, geckos

My leopard Gecko dropped her tail over a year ago and she still has not grown it back. 
It has healed and there is a stump there but it doesn't seem to be growing anymore. 
The stump is about the size of her head so OK but not back to it's original size. 
She is a bit retarded so I never know what to expect. 
Is this normal? am I missing something?